# Two different MX servers for when email doesn't exist in the highest priority MX

Tags: mx-record

I have a client who has a domain and wants to use two email servers:

- Server #1: It would have the email atendimento@
- Server #2: It would have the email comercial@

If I point the highest priority MX to "Server #1" and the lowest priority to "Server #2".
Would this work?

Answer (score 1):

MX settings are by domain. In a mail server you can host multiple domain.

If your customer want to have email sent to comercial@test.com send to another server then it mean you have to forward those email to another domain/alias outside the scope of the first server, to be receive on another server on another alias.

Comment: (bonus, not worth separate answer) A single piece of mail may be addressed to, or (blind) carbon copied to, to both mailboxes at the same time - even in arbitrary order. It therefore helps to imagine the desired forwarding as a *per-recipient* operation, even where as a result *messages* are moved between servers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would work.

Server #1 only knows the email address atendimento@, Server #2 only comercial@.

If you send an email to comercial@ Server #1 will reject the email.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, pointing the highest priority MX record to "Server #1" and the lowest priority MX record to "Server #2" should work for your client's requirement of using two email servers.

When someone sends an email to someaddress@yourclientdomain.com, the sender's email server will first check the MX records for your client's domain to determine where to deliver the email. If the highest priority MX record points to "Server #1," the email will be delivered to that server.

If "Server #1" is down or unavailable, the sender's email server will try to deliver the email to the next highest priority MX record. If the lowest priority MX record points to "Server #2," the email will be delivered to that server only if all other servers with higher priority are down or unavailable.